# Search in numpy object arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a **Numpy Object Array** of type `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`,

```
>>> xt4
array([['D', 'F'], ['B', 'C', 'E']], dtype=object)
```

But when I search for a specific value in the array using the **numpy.where**, it returns nothing, despite it being present.

```
>>> numpy.where(xt4=='D')
(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

Instead I was expecting the corresponding `[row]/[col]` index of that value from the array. This works fine with `int` but fails when I search for a string in an object array.

**Edit 1**

1. I do not have control over the object array and it is unlikely to be a square one.
2. I need the `[row]/[col]` index of the value present in the `nd.array`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a 1D array of objects, and the `==` operator on this command will simply try to match object to object. The simplest way to see this is like so:

```
>>> xt4=='D'
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Numpy tried to match `D` with `['D', 'F']` and `['B', 'C', 'E']`. You can have a char array like so:

```
>>> arr = np.array([['D', 'F', 'G'], ['B', 'C', 'E']])
>>> arr
array([['D', 'F', 'G'],
       ['B', 'C', 'E']],
      dtype='|S1')
```

Where any kind of boolean indexing will work just fine:

```
>>> arr=='D'
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(arr=='D')
(array([0]), array([0]))
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't have any control over the object array. Hence, is there any way I can search for a value in an array and get the corresponding index?

Comment: @PankajParashar You do this with python loops, but I do not believe there is a built-in function for this. Plus the "row/col" for the position does not make much sense here, you cannot use numpy indexing routines to access the `D` element.

Comment: Yeah. I can use for loops but the volume with which I am dealing with is huge and runs into 100k. Hence, I wanted to avoid for loops as much as possible.

Comment: Additionally, I don't understand why row/col position does not make sense to you? In this case, the expected answer should be row=0, col=0 which is going to be useful for what I'll be doing next. Did that make sense :-)?

Comment: @PankajParashar A numpy array is usually a contiguous chunk of data in memory. A numpy object array is just an array of pointers. Unless you can convert your data to a non-object array, most numpy routines will not work for you. Consider looking into [blaze](http://blaze.pydata.org) for non-uniform arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is NumPy doesn't really support jagged arrays in the same sense that it does others.  You can create them, but they don't always perform in the way you'd expect.
If each row in the array is the same length then it performs as expected.

```
>>> xt4 = array([['D', 'F'], ['B', 'C']], dtype=object)
>>> numpy.where(xt4=='D')
(array([0]), array([0]))
```

Comment: Agree. It still doesn't answer my question :) Also updated my question for more clarity.